# Oracle Apex issue

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have created 2 items,
Say - P1_ID and P1_MAIL
I want my form design like:
MAIL should automatically give the data when I will choose a value from ID field (LOV)
I have tried this by writing this SQL expression in SOURCE of P1_MAIL as:
Select mail from  where ID = :P1_ID. But still by running the app it's not working

I want this:
In form we have this fields:
ID
MAIL.. So when I am selecting any ID from the list, MAIL field value should come automatically...

In simple:
How to auto populate text fields based on selecting a record from lookup field..
Please help me if anyone of you have any idea

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include actual table names; your original post has an invalid SQL query `Select mail from where ID = :P1_ID` -- is missing the table name.  Provide a [mre] of the tables and data.

Comment: In real time I have written the table name
Select mail from table name where ID= :P1_ID... But still it's not working

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I am looking for.. how to auto populate text fields based on selecting a record from lookup field

Answer (score 1):

you have to create a dynamic action that fires on change of item P1_ID, under this dynamic action create an event when condition is true, select set value action. Under setting of the action select SQL Statement and type:

```
Select mail from /* your table*/  where ID = :P1_ID
```

remember to put the name of your table there, under items to submit put P1_ID and under affected elements select Item(s) and put the P1_MAIL item